# О чем должен говорить комментарий в коде?

Tags: любой-язык, code-style

О чем должен говорить комментарий в коде? О том, **что происходит** в следующем блоке кода или о том, что **должно произойти** в результате выполнения этого блока кода? Что в этом вопросе подсказывает/требует практика?

Comment: и то, и другое. Что бы через месяц не возникало вопросов вида "а что это такое? почему здесь -1 написал или удаляю этот файл?". Но без Капитана Очевидность.

Comment: Существует мнение, что наличие в коде комментариев говорит о его плохом качестве (DOC-комментариев это не касается конечно)

Comment: В рабочем коде выделенные вами строки эквивалентны

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Хороший комментарий — ненаписанный комментарий. Следует стремиться писать код так, чтобы комментарии были просто не нужны.

Проблема комментариев в том, что

- часто они находятся в одном месте, а помнить о них их нужно в другом
- компилятор не может проверить истинность комментария, поэтому при изменении кода комментарий устаревает

Пройдёмся по часто встречающимся случаям, в которых комментарии излишни.

1. Если вы хотите прокомментировать, для чего нужна какая-то переменная, выбросьте комментарий, и измените имя переменной на более подходящее.

   ```
   int n; // количество страусов
   ```

   лучше заменить на

   ```
   int numberOfOstriches;
   ```
2. Если вы хотите сообщить, что выполняется какое-то условие, лучше поставить `assert`:

   ```
   // тут pBFG не может быть nullptr-ом, проверка не нужна
   pBFG->fire();
   ```

   лучше заменить на

   ```
   assert(pBFG);
   pBFG->fire();
   ```
3. Если вы описываете в комментарии, что именно делает кусок кода, имеет смысл вместо этого выделить этот кусок в отдельную *функцию*, а смысл кода сделать её именем.

   ```
   // нормализовать вектор скорости
   double temp_length = sqrt(velocity.x * velocity.x + velocity.y * velocity.y);
   velocity.x /= temp_length;
   velocity.y /= temp_length;
   ```

   лучше заменить на

   ```
   void Normalize(vector& v)
   {
       double length = sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y);
       if (length == 0.0)
           throw argument_exception("zero length vector");
       v.x /= length;
       v.y /= length;
   }
   ```

   ```
   Normalize(velocity);
   ```
4. Если вы описываете в комментарии самоочевидные вещи, лучше этот комментарий просто выкинуть.

   ```
   // этот класс представляет точку
   class Point
   {
       public int X; // координата X
       public int Y; // координата Y
   }
   ```

   ни капли не теряет в читаемости в таком виде:

   ```
   class Point
   {
       public int X;
       public int Y;
   }
   ```

   (а если бессмысленные комментарии требуются от вас стандартами кодирования, потребуйте изменения этих стандартов!)

Таким образом, *что происходит* в участке кода, должно быть по возможности понятно из самого куска кода. Если это не так — улучшайте его.

Если комментарий представляет собой на деле документацию к вашему коду, тут ничего не поделаешь, удалять его не нужно.

---

Те немногие места, где комментарии действительно *нужны* — описания используемых алгоритмов, оптимизаций, документация багфиксов и неочевидных решений. Здесь снова-таки старайтесь писать о том, *почему* вы делаете так, как делаете. А *как именно* вы делаете, должно быть понятно из кода.

Answer (score 6):

*"Ну ты, барин, и задачи ставишь"...* (с) К/ф "Формула любви"

К комментариям нет требований. Понимаете, это все равно как спросить - рассказ должен описывать намерения автора или действия персонажей? Сама постановка странная - что именно писать в комментарии... А уж различать "что происходит" и "что должно произойти" - это уж совсем странно.

Вообще-то код нужно писать так, чтоб он сам по себе комментировал, что он делает. Придумано не мной, но я с этим, в общем-то, согласен. И уж точно не нужно комментировать в духе "присваиваем переменной сумму двух других" :)

Пишите комментарии так, чтобы вы через год-два могли глянуть на код и разобраться, что же он делает.

Отдельно я бы выделил комментарии о том, что надо не забыть сделать :)

Если работаете в команде - то работайте так, как решено командой.

Под конец процитирую Саттера:

*Не предписывайте стиль комментариев (кроме тех случаев, когда специальный инструментарий использует их для документирования), но пишите только нужные и полезные комментарии. Вместо комментариев пишите, где это возможно, код.*

Comment: `TODO` важны, да.

Answer (score 4):

Хорошие комментарии именно  *в коде* (а не перед функциями и т.п.)  должны пояснять **зачем** этот кусок нужен для решения задачи.

Вполне вероятно, что для понимания этого "зачем", потребуется описать состояние исходных данных и что получается после выполнения комментируемого кода.

А как именно это реализуется, желательно рассказывать *самим кодом*.